# How can I add function typings for static method chaning in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, methods, types, static, method-chaining

Image I have this little class with 2 static methods. Like this I can chain the methods as I want.

```
class MyClass {
  static x() {
    console.log("x");
    return this;
  }

  static y() {
    console.log("y");
    return this;
  }
}

MyClass.x().y();
```

If I wanted to add typings for the 2 methods how would the typings look like? In other words how can I define the correct return type?

```
class MyClass {
  static x(): MyClass {
    console.log("x");
    return this;
  }

  static y(): MyClass {
    console.log("y");
    return this;
  }
}

MyClass.x().y();
```

This doesn't work but hopefully shows what I mean.

Comment: Why do you need to define any type?  Let the compiler infer it as `typeof MyClass`, which is what you could annotate it as, [if you really want to](https://tsplay.dev/KN7JGw).

Comment: I know it does work without defining a type but i just want to have it there. OMG Thanks! literally forgot the typeof :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *type* named `MyClass` corresponds to an *instance* of the `MyClass` class, and as such does not have the static methods such as `x` or `y`.

Inside a static method implementation, `this` refers to the *constructor itself*, which (as long as you don't have subclasses to worry about) will be the *value* named `MyClass`.  The type of the `MyClass` constuctor is not `MyClass`, but `typeof MyClass`, using the Typescript [`typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator).

If you use IntelliSense to inspect the return types inferred for `x()` and `y()` in your example code, you'll see:

```
class MyClass {       
  // (method) MyClass.x(): typeof MyClass
  //     ↓
  static x() {
    console.log("x");
    return this;
  }
}
```

If you really want to annotate the type for some reason, `typeof MyClass` is potentially the right answer:

```
class MyClass {
  static x(): typeof MyClass {
    console.log("x");
    return this;
  }

  static y(): typeof MyClass {
    console.log("y");
    return this;
  }
}
```

---

Note that things get a bit trickier if you have subclasses and you want to capture the fact that subclasses have inheritance on the static side too:

```
class YourClass extends MyClass {
  static z = 123;
}

YourClass.x().z // error!
// ---------> ~
// not known to exist by TypeScript but exists at runtime
```

You probably don't care about that, but if you do it's an outstanding issue in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) for discussion and workarounds.  More information available upon request.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oHofQAoBbAUwBcALAewBMBKOJFCAOgA8C6AuaM+ABxJUAZo2SQIWaBDJgyAS2DQO3XgKGiE41JmzZgVAHYQqIEixBUA5gQBEbW3QDcU7ACdyAVzeHeFeRAu2AC+GFIycorQ8Jw8fIIiYszortAGxqbmlja28I5Beh5k3r6UAQWhoRhazOycLDHOYaAS0ACaVN7aMCRsZCSGNDA1rbrSsgpKAF7QALzQAIwATADMLlUdXbUqLDN40CRublRuAIQY+wC01zc3AHzQAH4X+IZUZNAA1m8A7qVUBzYAQ+ACN4NAACrqADKwDc8n4oM8H16wJgcmgbk8hgUpCAA)